# Bison how to describe optional syntax in grammar without shift-reduce conflicts?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, shift-reduce-conflict, ambiguous-grammar

I have a file that is described with a grammar. It has a section that can consist of one or two kinds of contents, and it can be in arbitrary order:

```
...
type_a_thing
type_b_thing
type_b_thing
type_a_thing
....
```

Or just

```
...
type_a_thing
...
```

or

```
...
type_b_thing
type_b_thing
...
```

or any combinations, in any number of occurences. Both type_a_thing andtype_b_thing has a well defined structure. I have managed to describe this so that the parser works, but I still get shift/reduce errors.
I have uploaded a minimal example here:

https://github.com/waszil/minimal_bison_parser

Is this the right way to address this problem? Am I doing it wrong?
I have tried a lot of things for this, checked the .output file generated by bison with the verbose flag, but I don't know, how should it be done properly. It is somewhat similar to the nested-list grammar problem that is described in the Flex&Bison O'Reilly book, but not the same

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't tell you why you get a shift-reduce conflict if we don't know the definitions of `type_a` and `type_b`.

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem may has to do with the fact, that type_b has a start and end token, but type_a does not?

Comment: As sepp2k says,  noone can help you unless you provide enough information. You can easily demonstrate that the current excerpt works just fine, by simply trying it.

Comment: Well, I have added extra info on the rules, but the thing is that this is only (a simplified) part of a quite large grammar, that I cannot put here, I just tried to concentrate on this part of the syntax, or to be precise, this kind of problem, that these sections can  follow each other multiple times. So this would be rather a theoretical question. But if needed, somehow I can send you the whole grammar description with an original input file, that is 5Mb big...

Comment: I have uploaded the sources with an example input file here: https://github.com/waszil/trcparser. The critical rules are actually in the rule "structures_and_typedefs" in TRC_grammar.y.

Comment: You're not supposed to post your entire real grammar, you're supposed to post a minimal-but-compilable grammar that reproduces the problem. This one does not. If I add the missing parts to your grammar and remove the `{...}` parts, then, as rici already indicated, it works fine - no conflicts. So clearly the grammar you posted here, does not include the problematic parts...

Comment: ... What you need to do is to post a grammar that's short enough that people will be willing to look through, but that actually contains the problem. If you post a grammar without conflicts, no one will be able to tell you why your real grammar causes conflicts. If you post your entire grammar, no one's going to bother to go through all that.

Comment: ... Which is what it says in the description of [mcve]. But the big bonus of making a [mcve] is that you often figure out the answer yourself while you are doing it, which aside from the sense of achievement it provides is also a great way of getting insight into writing grammars (or programming in general).

Comment: Ok guys, you are absolutely right. I have created a MCVE, can be found here:
https://github.com/waszil/minimal_bison_parser . I really cannot make it more minimal. It works on both input files, but still I get 2 shift/reduce errors. I have tried a lot of things for this, checked the .output file generated by bison with the verbose flag, but I dont know, how should it be done properly. It is somewhat similar to the nested-list grammar problem that is described in the Flex&Bison O'Reilly book, but not the same. Please, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your grammar:

```
contents:
    foobar
    | contents foobar
    ;
foobar:
    foos
    | bars
    ;
foos:
    foo
    | foos foo
    ;
bars:
    bar
    | bars bar
;
```

So `contents` is a list of `foobar`s, and `foobar` is either a list of `foo`s or a list of `bar`s. This is ambiguous because an input consisting of two consecutive `foo`s could be parsed as a `contents` by either interpreting the two `foo`s as a single `foobar` containing two `foo`s or as two `foobar`s containing one `foo` each.

An easy way to get rid of this ambiguity is forgo the inner lists:

```
contents: foobar | contents foobar;

foobar: foo | bar;
```

If you need consecutive `foo`s to be handled differently, you could still detect them during post-processing. If you absolutely need to handle this in the grammar, you can restructure the grammar so that a `foos` can only be followed by a `bars` (not another `foos`) or vice-versa.

Comment: Oh, it is that simple... Thank you very much, it works indeed. As for the grammar, it is not designed by me, it is a third-party file format that I have to parse.